# Expo typeorm migration commands throw Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, typeorm, expo-sqlite

I have an Expo project with `expo-sqlite` and `typeorm`. Relevant configuration:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "testproject",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  //...
  "dependencies": {
    //...
    "expo-sqlite": "~11.3.2",
    //...
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    //...
    "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata": "^0.3.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    //...
  },
  //...
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".expo/types/**/*.ts",
    "expo-env.d.ts"
  ],
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      // Required for expo-router
      'expo-router/babel',
      '@babel/transform-react-jsx-source',
      'babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata'
    ],
  };
};
```

data-source.ts

```
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from "typeorm";

export const options: DataSourceOptions = {
    type: "expo",
    database: 'TestProject',
    driver: require('expo-sqlite'),
    entities: [
        'entities/*.ts'
    ],
    //synchronize: true
    migrations: ['data/migrations/*.ts'],
    migrationsTableName: 'migrations'
};

const dataSource = new DataSource(options)
export default dataSource;
```

All of these files are in the root of the project (based on expo tabs template). Entities are in the `/entities` directory and migrations are in the `/data/migrations` directory

Attempting to run either `npx typeorm migration:run -d ./data-source.ts` or `npx typeorm migration:generate CreateTables -d ./data-source.ts` results in the following error

> Error during migration run:
> Error: Unable to open file: "D:\Programming\TestProject\data-source.ts". Cannot use import statement outside a module
> at CommandUtils.loadDataSource (D:\Programming\TestProject\node_modules\typeorm\commands\CommandUtils.js:22:19)
> at async Object.handler (D:\Programming\TestProject\node_modules\typeorm\commands\MigrationRunCommand.js:41:26)

I have tried using `npx typeorm-ts-node-esm` as well with the same result.

I have also tried changing the `data-source.ts` file to `data-source.js` and using commonjs style importing and exporting:

```
const { DataSource } = require("typeorm");

const options = {
    type: "expo",
    database: 'TestProject',
    driver: require('expo-sqlite'),
    entities: [
        'entities/*.ts'
    ],
    //synchronize: true
    migrations: ['data/migrations/*.ts'],
    migrationsTableName: 'migrations'
};

const dataSource = new DataSource(options);
module.exports = dataSource;
```

but I am getting the following error

> Error during migration run: Error: Unable to open file:
> "D:\Programming\TestProject\data-source.js". Unexpected token 'export'
> at CommandUtils.loadDataSource (D:\Programming\TestProject\node_modules\typeorm\commands\CommandUtils.js:22:19)
> at async Object.handler (D:\Programming\TestProject\node_modules\typeorm\commands\MigrationRunCommand.js:41:26)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: package.json doesn't officially support or document `the `module` field, but allows it because some older tools expect to find module syntax packages in `module` field of package.json.

Comment: is it possible that you've to move the ts-file in a subfolder, or change the configuration for include `**/*.ts` ?

Comment: were you able to find a solution? I am facing the same issue